# Meteor collection.find - return multiple values

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to implement a notification feature in meteor in combination with the meteor-roles package and I want to display the same notification to all users in a role.
I thought it is a good idea to store the main notification in the notification collection and a reference to the notification with an id and a "read" attribute in the user collection.
Otherwise I need to store each notification for every user in the role.

My db:

```
User Collection: "username": "UserXYZ", "notifications": [[{ "_id": "231", "read": "false"}], [{ "id": "3234", "read": "true"}]] …
Notification Collection: "_id": "231" …
```

And now I want to find the corresponding notification, but the problem is, that I can't tell the find function that I want multiple notifications displayed.

I thought something like this would do it:

```
notifications: function() {
    var user = Users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
    return Notifications.find({_id: user.notifications._id, read: false});
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the [mongo query operator `$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) can match against an array rather than one _id.  You would need to loop over each of the `user.notifications` to construct the array of _ids.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use aggregation to do this.  The `$unwind` operation allows you to make queries on individual notifications:

```
Users.aggregate(
    {$match: {_id: Meteor.userId()},
    {$unwind: "$notifications"},
    {$match: {"notifications.read": true}}
)
```

This will return each notification as its own document.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please show me how to use this aggregation properly with the collection.find() function? I tried it like this: `return Notifications.find(Users.aggregate(
            {$match: {_id: Meteor.userId()}},
            {$unwind: "$notifications"},
            {$match: {"notifications.read": false}}
        ));` But I always get an exception "from Deps recompute".

Comment: @user3475602 You can't use aggregation with `.find`.  That's why it's a separate method

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I also get an exception, when returning the aggregation. Could please tell me how to use it properly? What should I do with the aggregation query; how can I get my notifications?

Comment: @user3475602 the usual way would probably be to pass a callback to the `.aggregate` method. [See the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html?highlight=aggregate#aggregate) -- it's just the second argument to `.aggregate` with the native MongoDB driver

Comment: Thank you for the link. Well, I tried to execute the function on the client and on the server side and I always get an exception. On the server side: Exception while invoking method 'comment' TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'aggregate'. I think meteor does not support the aggregate function.